# Return Observable only after nested request is completed

Tags: angular, post, rxjs, observable

There are two POST-requests in this method:

```
public createArticle(request: IArticle) {
  const requestPath = `${this.backendUrl}/articles`;
  return this.http
    .post<IResponse<IArticleApiContract>>(requestPath, getArticleApiContract(request), {
      headers: this.headers
    })
    .pipe(map(processResponseItem))
    .pipe(map(responseItem => getArticlesModel(responseItem)))
    .pipe(
      map(article => {
        if (request.uploads) {
          const uploadPath = `${this.backendUrl}/articles/${article.id}/files`;
          const formData = new FormData();
          request.uploads.forEach(file => {
            formData.append('fileData', file);
          });
          this.http
              .post<IResponse<IFileApiContract>>(uploadPath, formData, {
                headers: this.headers
              })
              .toPromise();
        }
        return article;
      })
    );
}
```

The first one creates an article, and the second one uploads some files to the article.
How can I return `Observable<IArticle>` only after uploading request is done? Because this observable has a field `isCreated`, and I use it to close a modal window after submitting. But now I receive the observable before uploading is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mergeMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to fix your issue.

```
public createArticle(request: IArticle) {
const requestPath = `${this.backendUrl}/articles`;
return this.http
    .post<IResponse<IArticleApiContract>>(requestPath, getArticleApiContract(request), {
        headers: this.headers
    })
    .pipe(
        map(processResponseItem),
        map(responseItem => getArticlesModel(responseItem)),
        mergeMmap(article => {
            if (request.uploads) {
                const uploadPath = `${this.backendUrl}/articles/${article.id}/files`;
                const formData = new FormData();
                request.uploads.forEach(file => {
                    formData.append('fileData', file);
                });

                return this.http.post<IResponse<IFileApiContract>>(uploadPath, formData, {headers: this.headers}).pipe(map(() => article))
            }
            return of(article);
    })
    )
}
```

Comment: Edited: it was a mistake, all files are uploaded in one request

Comment: Thank you! I think it's what I'm looking for